# Кракозябры сообщений компилятора в QtCreator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qtcreator

При использовании компилятора Microsoft в Qt-проекте в окне сборки выводятся сообщения об ошибках и предупреждениях с поломанной кодировкой. Например:

> ```
> warning C4311: ЇаЁўҐ¤Ґ­ЁҐ вЁЇ®ў: гбҐзҐ­ЁҐ гЄ § вҐ«п Ё§ "Qt::HANDLE" ў "unsigned int"
> warning C4302: ЇаЁўҐ¤Ґ­ЁҐ вЁЇ®ў: гбҐзҐ­ЁҐ Ё§ "Qt::HANDLE" ў "unsigned int"
> ```

Как можно вывести подобные сообщения в адекватном читабельном виде, на русском или английском языках?

Comment: Может просто не ставить русский языковой пакет?

Comment: @VTT специально он и не ставился, насколько я помню. Вероятно пролез из-за того, что винда русская.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одно из возможных решений – скрыть для компилятора *cl.exe* файлы со строками языка ОС. В данном случае речь о локале `ru-ru` с идентификатором `LCID`, равным `1049`. Полный список идентификаторов можно посмотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx), стоит учесть, что там они указаны в шестнадцатеричном виде.

В зависимости от версии и разрядности компилятора, выбранного для Qt-проекта, расположение файла *cl.exe* может разниться. Например, для *MSVC2015 64bit* путь будет такой:

> ```
> {Коренная папка Visual Studio}\VC\bin\amd64
> ```

В MSVC2017 структура пути несколько иная:

> ```
> {Коренная папка Visual Studio}\VC\Tools\MSVC\{версия}\bin\Hostx86\x64
> ```

Имя конечной папки можно подсмотреть в настройках сборки проекта в QtCreator:

> [image: Compiler path]

Для MSVC2017 `x86_amd64`, представленная на рисунке, будет как раз соответствовать `Hostx86\x64` (завершающая часть пути).

По этому пути достаточно переименовать папку *"1049"*, например, добавив подчёркивание *"1049_"*, после чего выполнить пересборку проекта. Сообщения компилятора будут выведены на английском языке:

> ```
> warning C4311: 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'Qt::HANDLE' to 'unsigned int'
> warning C4302: 'type cast': truncation from 'Qt::HANDLE' to 'unsigned int'
> ```

Стоит заметить, что наличие папки с английским языком, т.е. *"1033"*, является необходимым для неанглоязычной ОС. Доустановить или удалить вовсе некоторые языки можно в установщике Visual Studio:

> [image: Установщик VS]

Answer (score 3):

Все верно, только не нужно переименовывать папки. В креаторе есть галочка "заставить msvc выводить в UTF-8
[image: Вот тут]

Comment: это же не ответ, а комментарий к предыдущему ответу, правильно?

Comment: а похоже, это лучше ответ, чем предыдущий

Comment: [Вроде как](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blame/603ea1c6799daa631665f09911873137b103499f/src/plugins/projectexplorer/kitinformation.cpp#L1486) в 2019 году только появилась данная опция.

Comment: ответы имеют особенность устаревать. Технологии меняются, баги фиксятся. И, как результат, одни ответы были правильные, а теперь стают другие.